# How to install a PHP IDE plugin for Eclipse directly from the Eclipse environment?

Tags: php, eclipse-plugin, phpeclipse, php-ide

I have a clean Eclipse Java SDK. I would like to make it suitable for developing PHP applications. So I need a PHP IDE plugin (or something like that). How could I install it from the Eclipse environment?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Easy as pie:**

Open Eclipse and go to Help-> Software Updates-> Find and Install
Select "Search for new features to install" and click "Next"
Create a New Remote Site with the following details:

Name: PDT

URL:  http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/4.0.1

Get the latest above mentioned URLfrom -

http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/index.html#download

Check the PDT box and click "Next" to start the installation

Hope it helps

Comment: I can't see any software except Zend CE Features > Zend Debugging feature. :(

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Will update the URL for future reference :-)

Comment: The URL has changed to the one in guy schaller's answer.

Comment: I think you're on to something here.

Comment: For newer versions, the path is Help -> Install New Software... and the link is `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/[name of your version]`, i.e. `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars` for the Mars release.

Comment: The URL that worked for me was [link] (http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.7)

Answer (score 35):

To install PDT (PHP Development Tools) for PHP development environment is better in Eclipse. The following are the steps to install PDT in Eclipse (I'm considering [version 3.7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Indigo)):

1. Open Eclipse (in my case Eclipse Indigo).
2. Go to Help --> Install New Software...
3. Expand the "Work with" drop down and select "Indigo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo".
4. Expand "Programming Languages" from the list.
5. Check PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature.
6. Click "Next >" at the bottom and follow the further instruction of Eclipse.
7. After successful installation of PDT: Go to Window --> Preferences and see the list as PHP at left panel.

Comment: Instead of PDT, you can also use "Aptana Studio" in eclipse for PHP

Comment: I changed from Aptana 3 to PDT because Aptana customizes Eclipse to a point where it's barely usable if you're used to Eclipse's default setup (which I use with both Java and C++).

Answer (score 6):

Open up eclipse, go to "Help -> Install New Software". Enter:

> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

entry from the "Work with" dropdown.

Under the "Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Developmet" category, select "PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature 3.1.1.201209101312".

Answer (score 4):

The new [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) for the repository is now http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release. In Eclipse: open Help -> install new sofware -> add. Then paste this URL in the location.

Mark the check boxes you want and click next.

Answer (score 4):

Help --> Install New Software
In work with select box , only I have selected Kepler - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
And then under Programming language category you can find PHP Development tool.

fyi :I have ubuntu

Comment: your welcome ,
but that is good just for this version I cannot say what is solution in next version of eclipse

Comment: The currently newest version of the URL is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars/

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be to go to http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt/downloads where you will find the URL to the most updated PDT, as most of the URLS listed above are hitting a 404. Then pasting the URL to eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest Way To install PDT

1. Run eclipse
2. Click on "Help", "Install New Software"
3. “Choose all available sites”, in search box type "php"(takes a while to load)
4. => “programming languages” => "PHP Development Tools", => PhP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature.
5. Restart eclipse
6. File new => other => php .
7. Should be able to follow from their

Answer (score 0):

The [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) which worked for me is http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.0/interim/.

See also Stack Overflow question *[Installing PDT in Eclipse - No runtime option .. only SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398101)*.

Answer (score 0):

**Eclipse for PHP Developers Package**

Looking for the Eclipse for PHP Developers Package?

Due to lack of a package maintainer for the Indigo release there will be no PHP (PDT) package. If you would like to install PDT into your Eclipse installtion you can do so by using the Install New Software feature from the Help Menu and installing the PHP Development Tools (PDT) SDK Feature from the Eclipse Indigo Repo >> http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

*Text grabbed from page:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/php_package.php*

Answer (score 0):

Updated for 2019: As previously suggested, in the latest Eclipse, go to "Install New Software" in the Help Menu and click the "add" button with this URL http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest/ that should show the latest release of PHP Development Tools (PDT). You might need to search for "php" or "pdt". For Nightly releases you can use http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest-nightly/.