# Installing PDT in Eclipse - No runtime option .. only SDK

Tags: eclipse, sdk, runtime, eclipse-pdt

Admittedly I am new to Eclipse. I have it configured properly for Android development but I want to add the PDT plug-in for PHP development. I have followed the instructions for updating PDT for the Galileo version of Eclipse located here ...

http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation

When I search through the available PHP tools the only option is the PDT SDK feature. I was looking for the runtime option instead of the SDK. I don't want to install the SDK for PDT as I just want to use it and not modify it. The PDT 2.2 instructions seem to have a runtime option but I want to install PDT 2.1 instead of 2.2 as PDT 2.2 has not been released yet. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I found the following URL and used it as the URL to "work with" in the Eclipse updater ...

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/2.0/interim/

This repository gave me the PDT 2.1 runtime I was looking for. I hope this helps someone else.