# How to use Eclipse for both Java and PHP?

Tags: java, php, eclipse, ide

There are [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers (190 MB)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-jee-galileo-SR2-win32.zip) and [Eclipse for PHP Developers (139 MB)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/galileo/SR2/eclipse-php-galileo-SR2-win32.zip)

I've already installed Eclipse for PHP.

I don't want to install another eclipse for Java.

Is it possible to use the same Eclipse for both Java and PHP?

**EDIT**

I decide to install another Eclipse for Java finally....

Comment: Could you answer your question? Why did you use another one? What was the problem with using both in one eclipse?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a PHP IDE plugin for Eclipse directly from the Eclipse environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397978/how-to-install-a-php-ide-plugin-for-eclipse-directly-from-the-eclipse-environmen)

Answer (score 5):

- Select Help -> Install new Software
- Select http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo as update site URL (or add it if it's missing)
- Select "EPP Java Package" and (if you want to write web apps) "Java EE IDE Feature" to install

Comment: @user198729: hm, that's strange. But I have to admit that I haven't used PDT

Comment: PDT doesn't tend to play nice with other Eclipse packages.  You can can coerce it into the same Eclipse by starting from Eclipse classic.  But even then I've found it to have issues.

Answer (score 3):

If you have trouble getting the Java plug-in into the prepackaged Eclipse PHP - as I have had in the past - then try returning to the eclipse.org site and downloading Eclipse Classic.  Then use the plug-in manager (Help->Install New Software) to install both the Java and the PHP plugins.

Comment: Can you debug both PHP and Java after doing it this way?I tried @Michael Borgwardt's solution only to find pdt is gone..

Comment: You can - however, you have to download an external debugger for the PDT.  Apparently licensing prevents them from packaging a PhP debugger with eclipse.

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend just keeping two versions.  I do.  I put alot of effort into coercing the PDT, Java and CDT plugins into one Eclipse, but never really got them all to play nice with each other.  I now keep three versions of Eclipse around - the pre-built package of each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just install the Java Plug-In

http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/
http://www.eclipse.org/callisto/java.php

Comment: I added the URLs with more Info. =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is go into the Help->Install new software  In the install window select "All Available Sites" in the "Work with:" drop down. Install the plugins to help you with your java programming.

Answer (score 0):

Do another installation so you have both as separate installs.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22679655/5375291) answer explains it all.

> So in your Eclipse:
>
> - click Help->Install New Software
> - In the "Work With" field put "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release"
> - Press Enter
> - You should see in "PHP Development Tools" check the checkbox
> - Click "Next" and follow the instruction to complete the installation