# How to use Eclipse for both PHP and Java?

Tags: java, php, eclipse

There are Eclipse IDE for Java and Eclipse for PHP.

I've already installed Eclipse for JAVA.

I don't want to install another eclipse for PHP.

Is it possible to use the same Eclipse for both Java and PHP?
What is the right process.please tel me.

Comment: That is not possible you need to install Eclipse PDT for PHP seperately.

Comment: Use Notepad++ for PHP. PHP doesn't require a specific folder structure or whatever.

Comment: I am working on cakephp.IS IT required the IDE?

Comment: No need IDE. Even notepad is good. PHP is an interpreted language not a compiler based or assembler based.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Eclipse for both Java and PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493085/how-to-use-eclipse-for-both-java-and-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install 2 Eclipse. You just need to download and install the PHP IDE plugin for the Eclipse you have installed.

Follow the instruction here:
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

Look into the section **PDT Repository**

Following I copy and pasted from the above link:

> To install latest stable PDT build,  open "Help -> Install New
>   Software" in Eclipse and enter following URL:
>   http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release

So in your Eclipse:

- click Help->Install New Software
- In the "Work With" field put "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release"
- Press Enter
- You should see in "PHP Development Tools" check the checkbox
- Click "Next" and follow the instruction to complete the installation

Comment: please give me the complete instructions.your giving the link is only for download.after download the plug-in how to config in IDE?

Comment: Oh no, you just read the top of the page didn't you :) I will update my answer.

Comment: after enter the pdt link it shows this error:    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) JUnit Tests 3.1.2.201212211235 (org.eclipse.php.test.feature.group 3.1.2.201212211235)

Comment: Yea that happens alot, just choose "PHP Development Tools (PDT)" you don't even need to install "PHP Development Tools (PDT) Mylyn Integration"

Comment: i am selected two options PDT,PDT mylyn also

Comment: after install this what i have do? i want work on cakephp applications in this eclipse ide.

Comment: That's whole other question about how to use the plugin. You might want to Google around.Start by going here: https://www.google.ca/search?q=cake+php+eclipse+IDE

Comment: Is any there path settings are needed after installation completed?

Comment: Installation compete please tell me how to develope a simple cakephp application by using eclipse.