# How to configure PHP-eclipse like Java-Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

I want to configure PHP Eclipse,means if I type letter It should show me PHP keywords, user defined methods and variables.

Comment: You can have a look at given url use PDT pluging for PHP  [ http://wiki.eclipse.org/PDT/Installation#Eclipse_3.4_.2F_Ganymede_.2F_PDT_2.0 ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PDT (PHP Development Tool) for eclipse.
See [Eclipse for PHP Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/marsr)

You can find your answer here too: [How to install a PHP IDE plugin for Eclipse directly from the Eclipse environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397978/how-to-install-a-php-ide-plugin-for-eclipse-directly-from-the-eclipse-environmen)

Using Netbeans and its PHP plugin would be a better option too